# Analyzing relationships in 5 time series (cointegration)

Tags: time-series, cointegration, independence, ardl

I don't have a dependent variable in this case. 5 time series correspond to 5 different sections of the same company. I want to analyze the relationships between the sections based on these 5 time series. **So I don't have a specific dependent variable.**
Using ADF unit root test, it was found that 4 series are I(0) and one series is I(1). Using ARDL requires a dependent variable. What can I do?

Comment: Since you mentioned ARDL (a model involving own lags and lags of other variables), maybe you want a vector autoregression (VAR) where every variable is a dependent variable? The integrated variable would have to be differenced first.

Comment: I am new to this area. How can I choose the number of lags?

Comment: You can use information criteria such as AIC or BIC. Software for VAR models often contain functions for model selection based on them (e.g. `VARselect` function in `vars` package in R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cointegration analysis requires that all time series are integrated to begin with. In your case, only one is integrated, so cointegration is not relevant. Since you mentioned ARDL (a model involving own lags and lags of other variables), maybe you want a vector autoregression (VAR) where every variable is a dependent variable? The integrated variable would have to be differenced first.

> How can I choose the number of lags?

You can use information criteria such as AIC or BIC. Software for VAR models often contain functions for model selection based on them (e.g. `VARselect` function in `vars` package in R).